# How to reduce and increase the font size based on screen size in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad

I want to reduce and increase the font size of the text in a UILabel based on the screen size. I'm trying to build for iPhone 5s to iPad Pro screen size (if thats possible). The labels are in a vertical stack view

Comment: There's no "auto-size" feature like that for font sizes. You probably want to build a table of the sizes you want to use, and then loop through your labels setting the appropriate size.

Comment: So no one has ever asked and answer this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this:

1. click on the label and go to the attributes pane
2. change the "lines" to 0
3. In autoshrink click on minimum font size and set it to about half the size of your main font or a much smaller font

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do that by changing the Autoshrink property of the label from its default value of Fixed Font Size to Minimum Font Scale.

Here I have attached an image to do that:

[image]

Comment: Set the number of lines to 0

Comment: The OP has labels in a vertical stack view. Try it with these labels: "Hello" "Goodbye" "This is a test" "This is yet another test label" ... see if setting Autoshrink will size them consistently across different screen sizes.